# Magento. Different addtocart button functionality based on different product types

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to assign certain "addtocart" to certain product type, and this what i have so far, any help will be appreciated.

This is my code so far.

```
        <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()): //add to cart when no options ?>
            <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <?php if($_product->getTypeId() == 'simple'): ?>
                <div class="add-to-box" style="text-align:right;">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart2') ?>
                </div>
            <?php elseif($_product->getTypeId() == 'bundle'): ?>
            <div class="add-to-box" style="text-align:right;">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is my code for having **different ADD TO CART buttons** for **different product types.**

```
<?php
        if ($_product->getTypeId() == 'simple')
        {
            ?>
            <div class="add-to-cart-buttons">
            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span>
            <?php //echo $buttonTitle; ?>
            <?php echo "Add Simple product to cart"; ?>
            </span></span></button>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        elseif ($_product->getTypeId() == 'bundle')
        {
                ?>
                <div class="add-to-cart-buttons">
                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo "Add Bundle product to cart"; ?></span></span></button>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
                </div>
                <?php

        }
        else
        {
            ?>
            <div class="add-to-cart-buttons">
            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
```

?>

I have added for **simple & bundle.** It can be added for other also.

I have added this code in `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml`